# Cdo operation error of invalid character at position 1! in nc file

Tags: cdo-climate

I am trying to execute the command

```
cdo subc,SCM5_His_mean.nc ob_MAMJ_mean.nc SCM5_His_mb.nc
```

but I'm getting this error:

> cdo subc (Abort): Float parameter >SCM5_His_MAMJ_mean.nc< contains invalid character at position 1!

The `SCM5_His_MAMJ_mean.nc` file was originally in curvillinear grid format and was interpolated to regular grid using remapbil in `cdo`. Where could be the problem as the interpolation returned satisfactory results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `subc` mean "subtract a constant" and needs a float or integer argument after it, e.g. the following command would subtract 273.15 from the field contained in temp_in_K.nc and put the result in the output file temp_in_C.nc (note that the meta data is not changed, however):

```
cdo subc,273.15 temp_in_K.nc temp_in_C.nc
```

If you want to subtract the field in SCM5_His_mean.nc from the field in ob_MAMJ_mean.nc, then the correct command is `sub`

```
cdo sub file1.nc file2.nc file1-file2.nc
```

the last name is the output

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for the answer. It worked.